# Are there ways to inadvertently expose the H2 Console?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, h2

I have a question about CVE-2022-23221 (https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-45hx-wfhj-473x,
https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-23221).
I have a Spring Boot application which uses the applicable library "h2database". I cannot update the impacted lib immediately and I am looking for workaround solutions. My questions are:

According to my research, the H2 console can by default be accessed on http port 8000. My firewall config only allows access to 80 and 443. That configuration would mean that the application is only vulnerable through yet another vuln, such as an SSRF vulnerability, for instance. My question is whether there is a possiblity that I accidentally make the console accessible by any other way that I am may not be aware of because there is no obvious connection to the console.

Something similar to the situation with JMX: Even if you avoid insecure JMX to your Java application by omitting the corresponding system properties when starting the JVM, your application is still vulnerable if someone starts the JMX-listeners programmatically in the code.

So essentially, my question is whether there exist any hidden pitfalls in the H2 DB area which would inadvertently make my app vulnerable even though the H2 console is not accessible from the outside world.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Well ... if some hacker could get into your network or machine by some route that could evade your firewall. Or another employee who happens to be a bad actor.  And yes ... there could be hidden pitfalls (e.g. undisclosed vulnerabilities) in H2 or in other software that you have installed that mean that your assumption that nobody can access port 8000 is ill-founded.

Comment: *"Thanks for any hint."* - My advice would be to look for ways to patch the CVE rather than looking for ways to put it off.

Answer (score 0):

H2 Console is like any other web other application which can be hosted on a said port.

As you mentioned the default port upon which the h2 console is serving the requests (8000) is not exposed by firewall. I do not see any visible issues right now.

Being said that CVE can occur from any source of (code, network, dependency) external exposure. it is best to limit the exposure of h2 from your production application in that case.

Hope this helps.